# Order of evaluation of pointer dereference operator

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dereference

I was writing some code for deleting the node from the doubly linked list and I came across a following syntax. Though I am able to understand what the syntax is doing but not able top get How is it possible below is the code

```
struct dll{
   int data;
   struct dll *next;
   struct dll *prev;
};
```

and in some function in there is this syntax

```
else{
  temp2=temp->prev;
  temp2->next=temp->next;
  temp->next->prev=temp2;
  free(temp);
}
```

I know what `temp->next` it makes the `temp` pointer point to the `next node` and from the syntax I could also understand that `temp->next->prev` will make the pointer point to the `prev pointer of the next node.`

But the question is how this syntax is evaluated ?

Comment: `temp->next == (*temp).next`, is that what you're looking for? I don't seem to understand this question

Answer (score 6):

I think you've misunderstood what the `->` operator does. It doesn't make `temp` point anywhere different, it just accesses a member from the structure pointed to by the first operand.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

The syntax is evaluated left to right, and operator precedence means that the structure dereference happens before the assignment. So the third line (for example) is really this:-

```
((temp->next)->prev) = temp2;
```

Comment: Okay agreed -> operator is used by the pointer of type some struct temp->next gets the value of the head of the next node rt so isn't this expression decomposed to (value at the head of the next node)->prev Am i missing something here ?